# c# if else looping

Tags: c#, if-statement

i need some help in the if else part. For now, my code shows "if row=0, user not found". But i would like it to loop whereby if nothing is detected, continues looping until the event changes. How do i do this looping here?

```
string strOleDbConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Project.mdb";
string strSqlStatement = string.Empty;
strSqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM jiahe WHERE [Tag ID] = '" + txt + "'";
OleDbConnection objConnection = new OleDbConnection(strOleDbConnectionString);
OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSqlStatement, objConnection);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
objAdapter.Fill(ds);

DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;

if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Not Found. Please register new user.");
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.Show();
}
else
{
    string strLine = string.Empty;
    string strUser = string.Empty;

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        string strTags = dr["Tag ID"].ToString();
        strUser = dr["User"].ToString();
        string strAge = dr["Age"].ToString();
        string strPhoneNumber = dr["Phone Number"].ToString();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "until the event changes"? By the way, you should use `using` statements to close your connections etc, and parameterized SQL to avoid SQL injection attacks and to keep your code and data separate.

Comment: I'm programming to detect tags using a reader. I would like to keep listening until a tag is detected. I've heard about avoiding SQL injection attacks by using statement, but i'm very new to c# and don't quite get it even after reading up.

Comment: In that case I would concentrate on learning more C# before you've written a lot of code with security vulnerabilities etc. It's possible that with *some* databases you could listen for the result of the query changing in an event based manner, but I suspect you'll basically have to query, check the results, sleep (or wait for the form to be completed), query, ... - basically a polling loop.

Comment: I think i got what you were trying to say. Thanks for the advice! Can you show me an example of a polling loop?

Comment: I suspect the whole design here is a little off - what are you trying to do when you've found the record? If `Form2` registers the user, why not hook into the end of that sequence? When the registration completes come back into this code programmatically, instead of *explicitly* looping? It's the same sort of effect, but in a more event-driven style.

Comment: Please ignore the registration of new user. It should flow this way..if rowcount=0, keep looping until a tag is detected and continue with else part. Which means in either cases, else must be implemented. Sorry i'm getting so confused i don't know if it should be written this way.

Comment: Esther: So there's no actual *action* to be taken if the record can't be found? What will the user be doing at this point?

Comment: You somehow guided me to what i wanted. Great help Jon, thanks!

Comment: I'm intrigued as to how I did that without understanding your problem, but I'm glad it helped somehow :)

Answer (score 5):

Just to expand my comment into an answer - it feels to me like this is going in the wrong direction. I would change the design to something like (somewhat pseudo-code):

```
void FindUserOrRegister()
{
    User user = GetUserFromDatabase();
    if (user != null)
    {
        new MainApplicationForm(user).Show();
    }
    else
    {
        new RegistrationForm().Show();
    }
}
```

Then *possibly* make the `RegistrationForm` logic call `FindUserOrRegister` as part of its registration flow - if the user chooses to just close the form, then the whole app should close (presumably)... but otherwise, when registration completes, you can close the form then call `FindUserOrRegister` again, which will then launch the main form.

Alternatively, the registration form could just launch the main application directly after registration has completed.

I'm sort of guessing as to what you're trying to do here, but I *do* think it's at least worth separating the database code from the UI flow - and trying to do this in a more event-driven way, given that it's the user who will be changing whether or not you should proceed. If you were waiting for *someone else* to add a record to the database, you would be better with some sort of timer repeatedly querying the database (in a background thread - threading is another area you'll need to learn about in order to avoid your UI hanging while you query the database, btw) but here I don't think you need that.